# What does p value = 1 mean in hypothesis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, inference, p-value

#H0: Median of Female population is lesser than male population <
#H1: Median of Female population is greater than male population >

```
wilcox.test(data$gender, data$dwelling_problems_safety, alternative="less", na.action = T)
```

I'm unable to interpret why p-value is 1 and what it mean, am i putting hypothesis wrong?

Comment: This is all too common a tale. Without a boxplot of `dwelling_problems_safety` against `gender` there's absolutely no way to know which direction the trend *ought* to be in. Always visualize your data. It's obvious one of two scenarios are playing out: 1) R has picked the wrong referent group for your one-sided test 2) the data are in complete contradiction to what you expected to see if the alternative were true.

Answer (score 1):

R is probably rounding a very large p-value to 1 (e.g., 0.99999).

But more importantly, that code is testing the location parameter of the variable gender against the location parameter of dwelling_problems_safety, i.e., you are not comparing dwelling_problems_safety between the two genders. You probably want something like,
`wilcox.test(dwelling_problems_safety~gender, data=data, alternative="less")`

Not sure why you had the "`na.option=T`", I don't believe that's a valid option for that function.

Comment: You mean to say that i have used comma instead of tilda, that's why not giving the results? does it matter if i change the location of x and y? "na.option=T" is because to skip the N.A Values in dataframe. Does it matter if i put in wilcox.test(gender~ dwelling_problems_safety, data=data, alternative="less") put gender first ?

Comment: Yes the order matters, Y~X says you want to compare Y at different levels of X. Also, I'm pretty sure you want na.omit then, not T for na.options.

Comment: When i put "," it gives me right hypothesis by boxplot, which say female is more then male with the dependent variable. but when i put "~" it gives me that male is equal female which is wrong by boxplot . any idea why?

Comment: When you put "," it doesn't test the hypothesis you want to test, so the results are meaningless.